# how to deal with POSIXlt format time using gvisMotionChart?

Tags: r

The `googleVis` package of R software is surprisingly good. However, I am puzzled by one problem of `gvisMotionChart` about the timevar, because the time in my data set is `POSIXlt` format, such as:

```
"2009-07-02 19:00:00" "2009-07-02 20:00:00" "2009-07-02 21:00:00" "2009-07-02 22:00:00" "2009-07-02 23:00:00"
```

Because the  time unit is hour, if I transform the  `POSIXlt` format to date format(using as.date), the hours information will be deleted and make the data nonsense.

So my question is: how to deal with the `POSIXlt` format time using `gvisMotionChart`?

Comment: In general, it will be easier to help you if you provide sample data and code.  See http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/602276 for tips on how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going by what is in the `googleVis` help there is no way to do this. You could transform your `POSIXlt` (or `POSIXct`) date-time data to numeric and it will work, though obviously the axis notation won't be as friendly as it could be.

I would try `as.numeric()` on your date-time data for the `gvisMotionChart` function, and then explore options to extend this if possible. I'm not sure if the limitation is with the `googleVis` package implementation or the Google Visualisation API, but that would be worth finding out. Either the R package and/or the API may be extended in the future.

Comment: I consult with Markus Gesmann, and he gave similar reply. "Unfortunately the Motion Chart does not accept POSIXt format for the time variable.
Please see the documentation and also http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/motionchart.html#Data_Format
You will have to either convert the POSIXt column into a number, or use alternative visualisations which support this format, e.g. gvisAnnotatedTimeLine." Thank you.

Comment: Ok, and it looks like the gvis API is limited to days so you are out of luck. That seems very limiting!

Comment: Is there any indication if the extension to include POSIXct/POSIXlt is going to be included anytime in the near future?